# Why do clip and intersect give different results (geometry)?

Tags: arcgis-pro, clip, intersect

I have a boundary (clipper) and street data (lines, clipee). I calculate the sum of the street length within the boundary for communities.

From a performance perspective this is faster to do over many communities at once, using an intersect, as opposed to select communities and clip individually.
However, to check the result, I clipped them individually and compared the result. The results differ in every community. I suspect this being some tolerance/precision setting, but cannot get at a different result manually setting tolerance. There is a visual offset between the clipped line and the result of the intersection.

Is there any other difference in handling of the geometries between these 2 tools that causes this?

ArcGIS Pro 2.9.3

[image]

Red line from intersection, blue line from clip. Light blue is the clipping polygon. Distance not really measurable in ArcGIS Pro, has to be below 1mm I think. Since the boundary sometimes goes along the direction of the street, the differences amount to several meters overall.

Comment: Are both your layer in the same CRS ? if not the tools may behave differently to reproject one or both layer

Comment: Can you share an example?

Comment: Product and version? Although `arcgis-pro` was tagged, it is good to state it in the question along with version

Comment: I assume you have checked the geometry of both layers, but you want to make sure the communities polygons have no overlapping polys prior to the intersect, and/or you might want to planarize your lines after one to get rid of line overlaps before recalculating your lengths.  You might  want show what is happening visually.  How much of a difference are you getting; at what scale are you seeing a "visual offset"?  When you say offset, do you mean one line is longer than the other or the lines have shifted relative to each other.

Comment: Added version and an image. Due to the nature of the work I cannot share data. Both layers are in the same coordinate system.

Comment: Edit your question to include details of the datasets format.

Comment: It looks like your municipal polygon boundaries that run along streets are not coincident with the streets.  Vertices might be offset and/or there may be many more vertices in one compared to the other.  If you 1:) put them in a topology and validate it, or 2:) you run the Integrate tool on them (use copies, the tool changes inputs), or 3:) snap one layer to the other (you may need to densify one first), and then run your Intersect and Clip tools what do you get?  Where streets cross boundaries I could envision a difference as Intersect would preserve line topology; clip results are separate.

Comment: @johns I think this could be a way to make both tools get the same result. Legally the data is not mine to alter though, so I am much more interested why the differences come to be, and which solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think this explains the select behavior really well and illustrates why the select behavior doesn't match with the clip behavior, but it doesn't explain why there is a difference.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/select-by-location-graphical-examples.htm